# Storyboard Illegal Configuration iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have moved from Xcode 4.6.2 to Xcode 5 GM and received such error:

Interface Builder does not support UITableView sizes larger than 10,000 by 10,000.
Does any body have the same problem ?

Comment: Do you actually have a UITableVIew of some insane size? (If not, you could always directly editing the storyboard XML and see if there's an  errant UITableView in there - look for a `<rect key="frame" ...` with an exceptionally large width/height.)

Comment: Can you please tell us why on earth you would need a tableview thats 15x the screen size?

Comment: Also I have found such thing: 
The UITableView with object ID WDe-Cv-8fg had a size larger than the maximum supported size, and has been changed from 1280.0 by 25112.0 points to 1280.0 by 10000.0 points.

Comment: Why on earth do you have a UITableView of that size?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the fact that a user has a stupidly sized UITableView.


Comment: This is a genuine question, i am having same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913495/xcode-5-opening-storyboard-file-hangs-and-ide-goes-to-deadlock. XCode 5 issue with storyboards.

Comment: After upgrade to 5 from 4.6 I have the same issue. It's not a stupid question. It's something the UI Builder is doing in the upgrade. It automatically changed my text view to 13321x799.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem was in one of my tables. There was a table in another table with such horrible sizes, that's why I didn't see it before. So I just remove it from there and everything looks fine.

Thank's everyone for help.