# Xcode 5 Opening storyboard file hangs and IDE goes to deadlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xcode5

I downloaded `XCode 5` lately to support `iOS 7`, on my `Macbook Pro` (8 GB DDR 3 RAM).

I have a **storyboard file which has close to 30 Controllers** in it.
I opened the storyboard file post that it got hanged due to which i am unable to proceed.

Here are the things i already tried:
1. Restarting `XCode`.
2. Restarting Mac.
3. Terminating all other Apps apart from `XCode`.
4. Cleaing all caches for `XCode` and clearing all content & settings for Simulators.

Edit: Compiler generates the below error:
***INTERFACE BUILDER DOES NOT SUPPORTS UIVIEW SIZES GREATER THAN 10,0000 BY 10000***

Please provide your answers on this solution.
I am unable to work on it and all development is halted.

Comment: Did you understand how I have solved that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823356/storyboard-illegal-configuration-ios-7?noredirect=1#comment27922558_18823356